# How to use Angular.js ng-repeat on simple object

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong with this? The list that it outputs looks all weird, the last element (correct one) gets misaligned from the rest. Also I need to run a function that randomizes the elements, where should that go?

```
<div ng-controller="getAnswers" id="pannel">
    <div id="base"></div>
    <ul class="answers">
        <li ng-repeat="wrong in answers.incorrect" class="answer" id="wrong{{$index}}">{{wrong}}</li>
        <li class="answer ng-scope" id="correct">{{answers.correct}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

$scope.answers looks like this

```
{correct: "작아",
incorrect: ["자가", "작ㅏ", "작"]}
```

Comment: The ng-controller name is a little weird, can you also post the controller definition with what exactly is set in the controller scope? Also you manually add ng-scope?

Comment: sorry, I actually worked this one out myself by putting everything into an array and setting a correct/incorrect property

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the data to this format and looping through it that way. Makes more sense to build the UL in one pass anyway.

```
[
{correct: "correct", text: "작아"}, 
{correct: "incorrect", text: "자가"}, 
{correct: "incorrect", text: "작ㅏ"}, 
{correct: "incorrect", text: "작"}
]
```